# Specify password in mysql connection string

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net, connection, connection-string

from C# program i have connect to mysql database
how to specify a password with a single quote character,
for get next error

```
Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification
starting at index
```

for this connection string

```
Server = srv; Database = db; User Id = user; Password = 'ktrnhjyyst;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote tokens that contain restricted chars:

```
var cn = "Server=srv;Database=db;User Id=user;Password=\"'ktrnhjyyst;\"";
```